# JSON.Net SerializeXnode excluding certain nodes

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone, json.net

I have a xml string that i'm trying to convert to JSON using JSON.Net. The problem is that i want only certain part of this xml in my JSON string. Below is the code i use and what i need.

```
var x = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x);
```

This will convert the whole doc. This is how json string looks like in a JSON Viewer
[image]

What i want is ONLY the table (The Arrowed one in image 1) and its descendants to be inside string json.

Is it possible? How to achieve it? Can i use a custom ContractResolver with SerializeXnode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an `XDocument`, so why not simply select the part you want and then serialize just that part?
Try something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var table = doc.XPathSelectElement("//table[@class=\"form\"]");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(table);
```

Note that `XPathSelectElement` is an extension method, so you will need `using System.Xml.XPath;` at the top of your code if you don't already have it.

**EDIT**

You can do it without `XPath` like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var table = root.Descendants(XName.Get("table"))
    .Where(e => e.Attributes(XName.Get("class"))
                 .Select(a => a.Value)
                 .FirstOrDefault() == "form")
    .First();

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(table);
```

Both approaches give the same results, the table plus all descendants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid i can't use it as system.xml.xpath don't work in Windows store app ;( Beside dose this approach gives me Table will all its descendants (which i need, OBS updated the question) or only the Table?

Comment: Many thanks, was testing this but different and faulty format ;). Will mark this as an answer.